# WrapInner does not set wrapper html

Tags: jquery

In my plugin I'm using the following code to wrap the contents of the provided element in a div:

```
  this.wrapper = $('<div/>', { 'class' : this.options.contentsClassName });
  this.element.wrapInner(this.wrapper);
```

In my `destroy` function I need to remove the wrapper div. However, it seems that using `wrapInner` does not actually set the `html` of the wrapper since:

```
this.element.html(this.wrapper.html());
```

Actually sets the original element's `html` to empty.

What would be the correct way to wrap/unwrap the content here? I'd like to store a reference to the wrapper in my plugin instance (`this.wrapper`) as I need to manipulate it in a number of areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `this.wrapper` refers to a JQuery object that isn't attached to the DOM. You'll want find the JQuery object that is attached to the DOM and store that.

Since you're wrapping the innercontents of the `element`, you can just set the `wrapper` to be the first child of the `element`:

```
this.element.wrapInner($('<div/>', { 'class' : this.options.contentsClassName }));
this.wrapper = this.element.children().first();
```

[Similar Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4uLTX/1/)